# How to send parameter from modalInstance to directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

Here my assignment:

```
 $scope.modalInstance;
 $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        template: '<commodity-form modal-instance="modalInstance" form="form" record="aaaaa"></commodity-form>',
        controller: 'CommodityFormcontroller',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
  });
```

Here is my controller

```
angular.module('collect').controller("CommodityFormcontroller", function commodityFormcontroller($scope, $modalInstance, form, record) {
       $scope.modalInstance = $modalInstance;
       $scope.form = form;
       $scope.record = record;
```

})

directive :

```
angular.module('collect').directive('commodityForm', function commodityFormDirective(CollectDataFactory, CommonFactory, dmapService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'js/collect/directives/commodity-form.tmpl.html',
        scope: {
            modalInstance: '=',
            form: '=',
            record: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

            console.log(scope.record, scope.form);
        }}}
```

paramenter form is work, but I have problem with record.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: resolve: function () {};

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass data from modal to parent controller?

1. When click ok or close in the modal, put this in `CommodityFormcontroller`

```js
    $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close('string or object');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
```

2. Put this where u open modal

```js
 $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function(result) {
  //here result equals "string or object"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    animation: true,
    template: '<commodity-form modal-instance="modalInstance" form="form" record="aaaaa"></commodity-form>',
    controller: 'CommodityFormcontroller',
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    resolve : {
      data : function () {
        return data 
    }}
```

});

The data will be availabe in the uib window by injecting data

```
modalInstanceController.$inject = ['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, thank  you guys

```
$scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    template: '<commodity-form modal-instance="modalInstance" form="form" record="record"></commodity-form>',
                    controller: 'CommodityFormcontroller',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    resolve :{
                        record: function(){
                            return angular.copy($scope.data);
                        }
                    }
           });
```